# Firestore retrieves weird data in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I have a list builder which displays text retrieved from Firestore.
the problem is the second text. It always shows "products" in second text. I tried to change the data in Firestore. But the problem is the same. It always shows second text as "products" other texts are perfectly fine.

"Products" is also the collection name.

here is the listbuilder.

```
 ListView.builder(
                itemCount: cart.length,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                  return Text(
                    products[i].data["product_name"] ?? " No Title",
                  );
                })
```

FireStore looks like

- products -> productid -> productname
- user -> uid -> cart[] array

I only take the products whose id is there in cart[].

Answer (score 4):

If possible can you share the structure for your firestore.

Because by looking at the code

```
ListView.builder(
                itemCount: cart.length,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                  return Text(
                    products[i].data["product_name"] ?? " No Title",
                  );
                })
```

in item count you are using 'cart' but in the Text widget you are using 'products' list.

Comment: carts is a list consisting the list of product id.

Comment: for example : cart = ["1","2","3"]

Comment: if cart["3","1","2"]
and product["1","2","3","4","5","6"]

then it will be an error for the listview. can you please provide the structure of the firestore how you are saving the data.

Because the cart count is not necessary it will be same as product.

Comment: I take only the products which are in the cart list.

Comment: by this 
QuerySnapshot snap = await _db
          .collection("products")
          .where("id", whereIn: cart)
          .getDocuments();

Answer (score 0):

My issue is resolved. Its is resolved in its own. I didn't do anything.
It resolved magically itself.